# Creating a matrix from data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df1` with 5 columns `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`, and `c5`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = c(1, 0, 1), c2 = c(0, 0, 1), c3 = c(2, 1, 0), c4 = c(1, 4, 3), c5 = c(1, 0, 0)) 

  #df1
  c1 c2 c3  c4  c5
  1  0  2   1   1
  0  0  1   4   0
  1  1  0   3   0
```

My desired output is:

```
  1  3  3   4  5
  3  4  4   4  4
  1  2  4   4  4
```

Basically, I am creating matrix based on the column number and its value (value is always less than or equal to 5). For example, 2nd row in `df1` has `1` and `4` belongs to column `c3` and `c4`. So, 2nd row in desired matrix would be `3 4 4 4 4`.

I have tried by myself. My code involves several nested control flows and not working well for a large data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little `apply` magic:

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) rep(row(as.matrix(x)), x)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    3    4    5
#[2,]    3    4    4    4    4
#[3,]    1    2    4    4    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different option

```
t(apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) rep(which(x!=0), x[x!=0])))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    3    4    5
#[2,]    3    4    4    4    4
#[3,]    1    2    4    4    4
```